# Does my ISP know if I upload files to a specific site when im using tor/whonix? Can it track all the traffic?

Tags: anonymity, security

As in the title.
I want to know If my ISP can see all the traffic if Its a brand new computer with no cookies and previous activities, using linux and a virtual machine - whonix and tor.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP knows 1 thing: that you are using Tor. They don't know where you go or what you do.

If you use a bridge, they don't even know that you are using Tor. This is to help people in countries where using Tor is a crime.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP will know only metadata of the communication to the tor relays.

It should be able to know the following:

- If you're connected to the tor network and when you're connecting (Note that Tor utilizes packet buffering, delays and shuffling techniques to protect from this attack class - reference: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Speculative_Tor_Attacks)
- The IP address of the first node you're connecting to